# Simple Recursive relation

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Suppose I have vectors `z1 z2 z3 z4` and `b` and matrices `D1 D2 D3 D4`.

I want to construct:

`b1 = D2*z2 + D3*z3 +D4*z4 -b`

`b2 = D1*z1 + D3*z3 +D4*z4 -b`

`b3 = D1*z1 + D2*z2 +D4*z4 -b`

`b4 = D1*z1 + D2*z2 +D3*z3 -b`

I planned to store my `z` vectors and `D` matrices in cells and extract them to create `b` by a for loop. e.g.

```
for i = 1:3

  b(i) = D{i+1}*z{i+1} + D{i}*z{i};

end
```

Of course it certainly fails because it involves `D{i}*z{i}` at each `i` step. Can you please help me to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this (no recursion, but still any pair-wise product is only computed once).

```
pairs = zeros(size(D{1},1), 4);
for ii=4:-1:1,
    pairs(:,ii) = D{ii}*z{ii};
end
```

Once you have the product of all pairs, you can take the sum

```
all_sum = sum(pairs, 2) - b_vec; % D1*z1 + D2*z2 + D3*z3 +D4*z4 -b
```

To get the proper `b_i` you only need to **subtract** `pairs(:,ii)` from the sum:

```matlab
for ii=4:-1:1
    b{ii} = all_sum - pairs{ii};
end
```